# Plotting a curve in 3D

Tags: plotting

Say I have two polynomials in $\mathbb{R}[X,Y,Z]$, whose intersection of zero loci correspond to a curve in the 3D space.

What is the best way to plot the curve?

### Example:

$$
f = X^2+Y^2-Z^2, \qquad g = 2X^3+Y^3-Z
$$
I want to plot the curve given by
$$ 
\begin{cases}
&X^2+Y^2=Z^2 \\\\
&2X^3+Y^3=Z
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 6):

Directly from [Highlight the Intersection of Two Surfaces](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/example/HighlightTheIntersectionOfTwoSurfaces.html)

Is this what you are looking for?

```
h = x^2 + y^2 - z^2;
g = 2 x^3 + y^3 - z;
ContourPlot3D[{h == 0, g == 0}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, 
   MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z, f}, h - g]}, 
 MeshStyle -> {{Thick, Blue}}, Mesh -> {{0}}, ContourStyle -> Directive[Orange, 
  Opacity[0.5], Specularity[White, 30]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Nice. How to do the same but with intersections of parallel planes with coordinate planes.